# Linq-to-Sql Base Class Discriminator Value BUG

Tags: linq-to-sql

In Linq-to-Sql Designer when I do not define "Base Class Discriminator Value" for abstract base class I get "The inheritance hierarchy rooted at 'X' does not define a default." run-time error, but if I do it I get "Abstract class 'Class Name' should not be assigned an inheritance discriminator key." error. What is wrong with it?

EDITED:

**I found the reason and solution myself. Please do not answer my question.**

Even if you know that you do not have rows in your database that do not match on any defined inheritance codes, anyway you have to set up "Inheritance Default" property for Linq-to-Sql. But you can't use your abstract base class as "Inheritance Default". So you have to create dummy non-abstract class which does nothing (throws exception in constructor etc.) and use it as "Inheritance Default". Leave "Base Class Discriminator Value" empty.

Comment: Why not add your edit as an answer to your question for future reference?

Comment: @Denis, post *edit* part of your question as a new answer, and then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I did mine by setting the default discriminator to 0, making the base lookup class a regular class and setting the default class to the lookup table. This doesn't require the use of a discriminator. I prefer this method for the reason of support. 2 years from now someone may go and delete the dummy record ( purposely or accidentally ) and take forever to find out why. It just keeps it simpler, but you do take a hit on the architecture. But, with all ORM's you always have to make that kind of decision.

I know you didn't want an answer, but I did this so if someone google's they know the alternative solution also. This allows them to make an informed decision.